# Bootstrap Navbar conflicting with another div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

I'm trying to add a simple Navbar to a (simple) Leaflet map. I'm having problems setting the Navbar and the map in each their own containers.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        
<!--    Leaflet-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
        
<!--    Jquery  -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
        
<!--    Bootstrap-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
        <style>
            html, body {height: 100%; margin: 0;}
            #map { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
<!--    Simple Navbar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">       
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">                 
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <select class="custom-select">
                            <optgroup label="Menu">
                                <option selected value="0">Option 0</option>
                                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                                <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                            </optgroup>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        
<!--    Div for my Leaflet map-->
        <div id='map'></div>

        <script>
            myMap = L.map('map')
            myMap.setView([0,0], 3)
            BgLayer = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
            BgLayer.addTo(myMap)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's what the result looks like:

[image]

On this screen grab, we can see that the map (and its zooming button "+/-") is behind the menu, meaning that the map starts at the very top of the browser window instead of at the bottom of the Navbar.

How could I (i.e by taking advantage of Bootstrap's containers?) make sure the Navbar and the map div don't overlap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` to resturcture the layout to fix the overlapping issue.

1. using a `d-flex flex-column h-100` container
2. using `flew-grow-1` for the map container to fit the rest of space and put the map inside

Hope it helps and Happy coding!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        
<!--    Leaflet-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
        
<!--    Jquery  -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
        
<!--    Bootstrap-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
        <style>
            html, body {height: 100%; margin: 0;}
            #map { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        

      <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
        <!--    Simple Navbar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light _fixed-top">       
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">                 
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <select class="custom-select">
                            <optgroup label="Menu">
                                <option selected value="0">Option 0</option>
                                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                                <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                            </optgroup>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        
        <div class="flex-grow-1">
          <!--    Div for my Leaflet map-->
          <div id='map'></div>
        </div>
      </div>

        <script>
            myMap = L.map('map')
            myMap.setView([0,0], 3)
            BgLayer = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
            BgLayer.addTo(myMap)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! However, this introduces a scrolling bar, and the bottom part (the main page containing the map) needs to be scrolled down to be seen completely. Which, in turn, hides the menu at the top. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Welcome! But mine here don't see any scrollbar, lets see the sample result here : https://codepen.io/zeikman/pen/KKxaJoR Not sure is there any other CSS that you had included but not positing in the script ?

Comment: My mistake, it works perfectly! Thank you so much once again :)